# Make player move back and forth in Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm wondering how to make a square player move back and forth with the arrow keys. I have tried `t.setheading()` and `t.forward(10)` but they don't work.

I think I am using 3.0
-_- I might just go back to scratch if this can not be fixed.

Comment: Can you post the smallest minimal program that will show what is going on here?

Comment: player = t.Turtle()
    player.ht()
    player.penup()
    player.color('maroon')
    player.shape('square')
    player.speed(999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)
    player.goto(-400, -30)
    player.st()
    player.speed(99)

Answer (score 1):

> I think I am using the version right before 3.0

Is that a code phrase for Python 2.7?

> i'm wondering how to make a player move back and forth with the arrow
>   keys

Below is my minimalist solution that should work in either Python 2 or Python 3:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from functools import partial

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(shape='square')
turtle.setheading(0)

screen.onkey(partial(turtle.forward, 10), "Right")
screen.onkey(partial(turtle.backward, 10), "Left")
screen.listen()

mainloop()
```

Comment: that just broke it.

Comment: @thepythonist, "that just broke it" isn't helpful. This looks like a reasonable solution. _Specifically_, what do you mean?

Comment: @chris all it did was blank out the screen so everything was white again. also i can't take screenshots.

Comment: That _probably_ generated an error message. That error message is _probably_ helpful in finding the cause of your problem.